# Handlebars.js - Combining Templates

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, behance-api

Each section of my code below creates a new handlebars.js template to call the "User Behance API". As you can see, each section has similar code, with a variable or two difference.

Is there a way to clean up this code, and combine these separate functions into one? Just seems like a lot of code, but then again I am new to handlebars.

```
// BEHANCE API INFO ---
var apiKey = 'ZLBxK9rEfHwJf9K0rmseNr2fS2gS2HJW';
var userID = 'creativemints';
var perPage = 10;
var behanceUserAPI = 'http://www.behance.net/v2/users/' + userID + '?callback=?&api_key=' + apiKey;
var behanceProjectAPI = 'http://www.behance.net/v2/users/' + userID + '/projects?callback=?&api_key=' + apiKey + '&per_page=' + perPage;

// BEHANCE - USER HEADER ---
(function () {
    function setUserTemplate() {
        var userData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('behanceUser')),
            getTemplate = $('#userHead').html(),
            template = Handlebars.compile(getTemplate),
            result = template(userData);
        $('header').html(result);
    }
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('behanceUser')) {
        setUserTemplate();
    } else {
        $.getJSON(behanceUserAPI, function (user) {
            var data = JSON.stringify(user);
            sessionStorage.setItem('behanceUser', data);
            setUserTemplate();
        });
    }
})();

// BEHANCE - USER ABOUT ---
(function () {
    function setUserTemplate() {
        var userData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('behanceUser')),
            getTemplate = $('#userAbout').html(),
            template = Handlebars.compile(getTemplate),
            result = template(userData);
        $('.about').html(result);
    }
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('behanceUser')) {
        setUserTemplate();
    } else {
        $.getJSON(behanceUserAPI, function (user) {
            var data = JSON.stringify(user);
            sessionStorage.setItem('behanceUser', data);
            setUserTemplate();
        });
    }
})();

// BEHANCE - USER FOOTER ---
(function () {
    function setUserTemplate() {
        var userData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('behanceUser')),
            getTemplate = $('#userFoot').html(),
            template = Handlebars.compile(getTemplate),
            result = template(userData);
        $('footer').html(result);
    }
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('behanceUser')) {
        setUserTemplate();
    } else {
        $.getJSON(behanceUserAPI, function (user) {
            var data = JSON.stringify(user);
            sessionStorage.setItem('behanceUser', data);
            setUserTemplate();
        });
    }
})();

// BEHANCE - USER COPYRIGHT ---
(function () {
    function setUserTemplate() {
        var userData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('behanceUser')),
            getTemplate = $('#userCopyright').html(),
            template = Handlebars.compile(getTemplate),
            result = template(userData);
        $('#copyright').html(result);
    }
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('behanceUser')) {
        setUserTemplate();
    } else {
        $.getJSON(behanceUserAPI, function (user) {
            var data = JSON.stringify(user);
            sessionStorage.setItem('behanceUser', data);
            setUserTemplate();
        });
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested this but you should be able to simply the code to something similar to this

```
// BEHANCE API INFO ---
var apiKey = 'ZLBxK9rEfHwJf9K0rmseNr2fS2gS2HJW';
var userID = 'creativemints';
var perPage = 10;
var behanceUserAPI = 'http://www.behance.net/v2/users/' + userID + '?callback=?&api_key=' + apiKey;
var behanceProjectAPI = 'http://www.behance.net/v2/users/' + userID + '/projects?callback=?&api_key=' + apiKey + '&per_page=' + perPage;

// BEHANCE - USER HEADER ---
(function () {

function setUserTemplate(templateSelector, htmlSelector) {
    var userData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('behanceUser')),
        getTemplate = $(templateSelector).html(),
        template = Handlebars.compile(getTemplate),
        result = template(userData);
    $(htmlSelector).html(result);
}

if (!sessionStorage.getItem('behanceUser')) {
    $.getJSON(behanceUserAPI, function (user) {
        var data = JSON.stringify(user);
        sessionStorage.setItem('behanceUser', data);
    });
}

setUserTemplate('#userHead','header');
setUserTemplate('#userAbout','.about');
setUserTemplate('#userFoot','footer');
setUserTemplate('#userCopyright','#copyright');
})();
```

Comment: You rock. This worked great. Half the code and running along!